# Is there anything wrong with this mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

Please take a look at the following query:

```
SELECT tc.registered, t.id, u.x_account_username
                        FROM x_trybe_comments tc
                        LEFT JOIN x_user u
                        ON tc.profile_id = u.id
                        LEFT JOIN x_trybes t
                        ON tc.trybe_id = t.id
                        WHERE u.id IN ('%s')
                        AND tc.trybe_id IN ('%s')

$query      =   sprintf($query, $contacts, $trybes);
```

I'm trying to select all comments from x_trybe_comments, whose my contact

> i.e. u.id IN ('%s')

AND in my trybes

> i.e. tc.trybe_id IN ('%s')

The '%s' are replaced with implode()'s of arrays.

I get the arrays from two functions as follows:

```
    $contacts = getContactIds($db,$profile_id);
    $trybes = getTrybesJoinedOrOwned($db,$profile_id);
    $contacts = implode("', '", $contacts);
    $trybes = implode("', '", $trybes);
```

Ouput for trybes and contacts:

```
Trybes: c341f36cc31c7e22c4ec00fd484c1fc03a7b2dfd', 'baa764365ac0a4ba044651ca46b08aa8de74e288', 'a9f4fba45750075eccda69f6645d6240c8889b10', '4ce48a7c7c21f82dc632bde72305d1330e1ac28 

Contacts: 1dd36ac747735a3ee8a1d47750e1515ab7ac0d53', 'dc19818afa52859032bdde290b900e3763ba54d0', '397cde4302885e167004494340971f4550346e04', 'c73fb8efa74354e721a5a945a5c367f486a3d80b', 'c484c72086ed2fdbd859954a2a753b07c4bd1f1d
```

Here is an echo of the query in question:

```
SELECT tc.registered, t.id, u.x_account_username
                        FROM x_trybe_comments tc
                        LEFT JOIN x_user u
                        ON tc.profile_id = u.id
                        LEFT JOIN x_trybes t
                        ON tc.trybe_id = t.id
                        WHERE u.id IN ('1dd36ac747735a3ee8a1d47750e1515ab7ac0d53', 'dc19818afa52859032bdde290b900e3763ba54d0', '397cde4302885e167004494340971f4550346e04', 'c73fb8efa74354e721a5a945a5c367f486a3d80b', 'c484c72086ed2fdbd859954a2a753b07c4bd1f1d')
                        AND tc.trybe_id IN ('c341f36cc31c7e22c4ec00fd484c1fc03a7b2dfd', 'baa764365ac0a4ba044651ca46b08aa8de74e288', 'a9f4fba45750075eccda69f6645d6240c8889b10', '4ce48a7c7c21f82dc632bde72305d1330e1ac280', '408032a6043f6789083c4919474969f6d47abb1c', 'f8fbf59d242794cc6c00932a8ef643587338d189', '76fb8332f5808111f6e83e5a8f9068ff911850e5', 'd62243e0026e8d4c48143549b421e492ba1a840f', '580861afde002c536466db9ae953e43c47b3eeab', 'faebdc82b8bcf8fbb5db56c3c3b805f3e1fda5a2', '297cebfa7522e253d65d1fd6f5f904ca5b626905')
```

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your implode statement?

Comment: @choult see bottom of question for implode statements

Comment: The `echo` of `$trybes`, `$contacts` variables is...? And also the SQL query itself - I suspect that the query itself is not build without syntax errors.

Comment: @bodi0 adding output for trybes and contacts now, please see bottom of question

Comment: Yep, you have missing quotes.

Comment: Try to look at the real query passed to the server using any profiler and you will understand where is the problem.

Comment: @bodi0 I'm not, They are added at the sprintf! ('%s')

Comment: @HamletHakobyan i've added an echo of the query to the question, please have a look, thanks

Comment: @MikeW theres nothing wrong with my mysql_query() function as i've been working with it for years now. It's something in the query string itself, i've added it to the end of the question, please take a look

Comment: OK, no syntax errors in your real query, but what happens if `tc.profile_id` or `u.id` is missing, can you post your database schema?

Comment: Your query look OK. If you haven't get any result, then you have no records that meet to predicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot, I was returning the $result object instead of my $array of data

Thanks for commenting, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the query, yes.  First problem:  you are using `left join`, but the `where` conditions are undoing the `left join`, turning it into a mere `inner join`.  The problem is that column values are `NULL` in unmatched rows, and the `where` clause does not take this into account.

The right solution is to move the conditions to the `on` clauses:

```
SELECT tc.registered, t.id, u.x_account_username
FROM x_trybe_comments tc LEFT JOIN
     x_user u
     ON tc.profile_id = u.id AND u.id IN ('%s') LEFT JOIN
     x_trybes t
     ON tc.trybe_id = t.id AND tc.trybe_id IN ('%s');
```

Or, if you really mean `INNER JOIN`, which seems likely:

```
SELECT tc.registered, t.id, u.x_account_username
FROM x_trybe_comments tc INNER JOIN
     x_user u
     ON tc.profile_id = u.id INNER JOIN
     x_trybes t
     ON tc.trybe_id = t.id 
WHERE u.id IN ('%s') AND tc.trybe_id IN ('%s');
```

The next problem is that the `in` condition will only work for one value.  `in ('2,3')` is different from `in (2,3)`.  One way to solve this is by putting the values into the query.  Another is to use `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT tc.registered, t.id, u.x_account_username
FROM x_trybe_comments tc INNER JOIN
     x_user u
     ON tc.profile_id = u.id INNER JOIN
     x_trybes t
     ON tc.trybe_id = t.id 
WHERE find_in_set(u.id, '%s') AND find_in_set(tc.trybe_id, '%s');
```

I would consider `find_in_set()` to be the quick/dirty solution.  Actually fixing the query is better because it can then use indexes and does not use a MySQL-specific function.